# How to get fixed disk drive letters in three seperate text files using batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, disk, drive

I am running the following batch program,

```
:hdd
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
         if %%d equ Fixed (
            echo %%c >hdd.txt
         )
      )
   )
)
```

it stores fixed disk letter to `hdd.txt` output on hdd.txt, `D:`

but, i have three fixed disks,

```
local disk C:
local disk D:
local disk E:
```

How to get three Fixed disks letter in three different text files ?

for example,

`C:` in `hdd1.txt`

`D:` in `hdd2.txt`

`E:` in `hdd3.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You could use this which doesn't require administrative privileges:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In (
    'WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='3'" Get DeviceID'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do (Set/A i+=1
            Echo %%B>"hdd!i!.txt")
```